# Getting all the users same child in Firebase (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building an app in Firebase and I want to get all the users pineapple rate.

This is the tree:

```
user1: uid1 {
  fruits: {
    apple: 3
    pineapple: 5
  }
}

user2: uid2 {
  fruits: {
    apple: 4
    pineapple: 2
  }
}
```

I tried this code:

```
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
ref.queryOrderedByChild("fruits")
            .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
                    print("not found")
                } else {
                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        let rate = child.value["pineapple"] as! String
                        print(rate)
                    }
                }
            })
```

But it gives me an error of unwrapping Nil.

Picture of the structre:

[image]

Comment: can you please post your structure

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Added in post

Comment: ok let me check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposed to be like this

```
  var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
     ref.queryOrderedByChild("user2")
        .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                for child in (snapshot.value?.allValues)! {
                    if let fruits = child["Fruits"] as? [String:String]{
                        let rate = fruits["pineapple"]
                        print(rate)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Why does the `fruits` and `userid` is in the same trunk? I want the fruits inside the `user` trunk

Comment: fruits is object that is available in every child .. .same as userid ... so your structure should be like this ... rather make fruits inside user ... its very complex structure and needless too

Comment: and if you don't want to make this structure ... I'll post an answer for your structure too if you want .. but there is one problem is that your user1, user2 is not unique at all ... it should be in key:value pair

Comment: It would be great if you'll do it because I don't under what trunk fruit and user is

Comment: Then how do I implement the user2 and his fruits rates?

Comment: @Eliko I'm not sure this solution answers the question *I want to get all the users pineapple rate.* as it's only getting user2 information. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question (which is quite possible)

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 please answer my question f Firebase swift here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646255/retrieve-all-child-value-to-a-label-in-table-view-cell thanks in advance

Comment: @Xcodian whats the problem in that?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 the problem is how can i access all children value of sub node of firebase to label in table view cell

Comment: @Xcodian the thing is if you want all your cake data like name, rate, image etc. in one node then you need to change your structure little bit and place one auto generated id in cake node and add single cake data in to that

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 i can do that sir, but i want to change the values through my console daily and i want the values that i will change daily in firebase console on cake node should get by app in realtime so i want a snapshot of all cake data to a label in table view cell only just retrieve all value rate in table view cell. however the names and images are static so i will put in them

Comment: @Xcodian so you want to retrieve rates only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137734/discussion-between-ei-captain-v2-0-and-xcodian).

Answer (score 0):

It seems this just needs a deep query?

```
    let ref = self.myRootRef.child("parent_node")

    ref.queryOrderedByChild("Fruits/pineapple").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { 
       snapshot in

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {

                let key = child.key as String
                let dict = child.value["Fruits"] as! NSDictionary
                let pineapple_count = dict["pineapple"] as! Int
                print("key = \(key)  count = \(pineapple_count)")

            }
        }
    })
```

and the output is

```
key = uid_1  count = 1
key = uid_0  count = 3
key = uid_2  count = 21
```

Comment: Is  this legal?: `Fruits/pineapple`

Comment: @Eliko It is! It's one way to form a deep query. Try my code, it's tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code below (Xcode 8.3.3, Swift 3 and Firebase 3 )

```
   var ref = Database.database().reference().child("fruits")

   ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {                
                (snapshot) in
         if let fruitPost = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                 for(key, value) in fruitPost {
                      if let fruitData = value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                             if let fruits = fruitData["pineapple"] as? String{
                                     let rate = fruits
                                        print(rate)
                                   }            
                              }
                          }
                    }
```

Goodluck mate!